# jQuery().slider is not a function error on Opencart 2

Tags: filter, opencart

I am using opencart 2.x version. After installation filter is not working. Please advise me.

Site Url : http://chotamart.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=34

Error Message :
TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function

Comment: Check your issue on the following demo site. May be it will help you.
[link](http://demo.brainyfilter.com/Office-equipment/Scanners) <br/>
**`http://demo.brainyfilter.com/Office-equipment/Scanners`**

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use both Jquery and ui, then it will work.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```